# Where can you find alcohol for potions?

Tags: the-witcher

Only *strong alcohol* can be used to create potions. Depending on the alcohol *type*, you can mix a certain number of ingredients:

- potion base = 3 ingredients
- high potion base = 4 ingredients
- top potion base = 5 ingredients

There is also a special potion called *White Gull* which is a top potion base itself, giving 5 slots to use to create another potion.

Alcohol is usually sold by waitresses at inns.

Can anyone list or map the places where it's possible to buy/find strong alcohol?